# Firefox: how do I configure kiosk mode?

Tags: command-line, firefox, browser, command-line-arguments, kiosk

[Mozilla's website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode) states:

> Numerous features of the kiosk mode are configurable through policy or
> command line parameters when launching the browser.

However, other than a single example to run kiosk mode as a private window, it doesn't seem to provide any information on how to access such configuration. I couldn't seem to find the information anywhere else either.

How can I configure kiosk mode?

EDIT: there seems to be some confusion about what I'm looking for. I'm already aware that I can pass other, *non-kiosk related*, arguments via the command line. I'm specifically looking at how I can configure *kiosk* mode itself in line with the quoted text above.

Answer (score 0):

I did a brief search on this and found the following information. The first link is an explanation from Mozilla on how to initiate kiosk mode. I didn't see any other CLI options there so I did another search which led me to the second link. This link is a comprehensive list of CLI options that Firefox allows. I imagine this should be sufficient to get you moving further. Hope this helps!

[EDIT] To add additional clarity to my answer if you look at the first link I referenced the excerpt the OP quotes is under the **Recommended configuration** heading. Under that heading are subheadings **Command Line Arguments** and **Policy configuration**. Both subheadings are explicitly referenced in the quote the OP provided. The **Command Line Arguments** subheading is what the OP is asking about. Under this heading a brief example is provided with a simple explanation.

All command line arguments for Mozilla Firefox Command Line are located within the second link that I referenced.It doesn't matter whether you're using kiosk mode or doing general configurations via the CLI. All information for Command Line Arguments will be located in the second link. There's no additional page containing Command Line Argument information/explanation. Feel free to search their wiki which is where the information in that second link is from.

You can also cross reference the information from the example in the first link with their Command Line Argument documentation. Additionally, if you look at the Command Line Arguments documentation it clearly states that `--kiosk` only accepts a single value and that's a URL of the page you'd like open when Firefox starts.

Sources

1. [Firefox Enterprise Kiosk Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode)
2. [Firefox/CommandLineOptions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions)

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I'm already aware of which other command line arguments can be passed to Firefox. What I'm looking for is how to pass options to configure the `kiosk` command line argument specifically.

Comment: If you look at the second link that I provided that information is in there. For the -kiosk CLI option only a single value is passed and that's a URL. Any additional functionality would have to come from using other CLI options in combination. Not only that but the excerpt that you referenced states "Command Line Parameters" which is going to be in the second link I provided. The example in the documentation that we both reference is -kiosk -private-window [target URL]. If you look those are both separate options listed in the documentation I provided.

Comment: As I said, I'm aware of other command line arguments. Yes, I know that that means I can for example *combine* `--kiosk` (which provides kiosk functionality) with `--private-window` (which provides a private window). I'm not interested in how to do that. My question refers specifically to this: "*Numerous features of the kiosk mode are configurable*". I'm looking for information on how to access and modify these configurable options for `kiosk` specifically, not how to combine with other (non-kiosk) features.

Comment: If you look at where  "Numerous features of the kiosk mode are configurable" they list "Policy configuration" and  "Command Line Arguments" after that where the referenced example is. That's essentially Mozilla telling you that those additional features are listed in the second documentation that I linked. I think it's clear at this point you either don't understand documentation or don't understand what you're actually asking for

Comment: `--kiosk URL

Open URL full screen without user interface. Firefox 71 and later.`

This means that `--kiosk` only has one argument that can be provided and that is a URL. Nothing else. Any other functionality is going to be provided through additional CLI arguments. ALL OF WHICH are listed in that second link. You literally can't argue with this as it's coming from Mozilla's documentation. If you have any arguments with this it means you're not taking the time to understand this.

Comment: Thanks again (although I would have preferred if you could state your opinion without being rude). We'll have to agree to disagree. To me, "numerous features of the kiosk mode" does *NOT* imply that there is "only one argument that can be provided". The word "numerous" and the word "one" are clearly mutually exclusive. I'd be willing to accept (if it can be shown to be the case) that the quoted sentence is *wrong* (i.e. there aren't "numerous configurable features" as Mozilla state), but in the absence of that your reasoning doesn't pan out.

Comment: It also doesn't follow that the other, *unrelated* CLI arguments which you can pass could be considered "features of kiosk mode", since they are completely independent of kiosk mode. You've also not addressed how you consider that kiosk mode could be configured via "policy configuration" (which you referred to but didn't elaborate on).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My friends it's clear at this point that you don't understand the documentation you're reading. It's also even more clear that you opened this question with a closed mind and a preconceived notion. You're resistance isn't even logically founded. Basically you're under the assumption that there's going to be a list of CLI arguments for kiosk mode which is clearly not the case. The standard for CLI tools is that all options and arguments are contained in a singular document unless stated otherwise. Please provide some proof rather than overly reading into a single line.